# delete[] an array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator, delete-operator

I have allocated and array of Objects

```
Objects *array = new Objects[N];
```

How should I delete this array?
Just

```
delete[] array;
```

or with iterating over the array's elements?

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    delete array[i];
delete[];
```

Thanks

UPDATE:

I changed loop body as

```
delete &array[i];
```

to force the code to compile.

Comment: will this be array of pointers or pointer to array?

Comment: Doing this: 'delete &array[i];' is incorrect. You did not use new to allocate the element array[i] so you should not delete it. Delete the whole array.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Every use of `new` should be balanced by a `delete`, and every use of `new[]` should be balanced by `delete[]`.

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    delete array[i];
delete[] array;
```

That would be appropriate only if you initialized the array as:

```
Objects **array = new Objects*[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
    array[i] = new Object;
}
```

The fact that your original code gave you a *compilation error* is a strong hint that you're doing something wrong.

BTW, obligatory: avoid allocating arrays with `new[]`; use `std::vector` instead, and then its destructor will take care of cleanup for you.  Additionally it will be exception-safe by not leaking memory if exceptions are thrown.

Comment: No!  Don't use std::vector blindly as a substitute for arrays!  That's like saying "I have a transportation need, so I'll use a car."  Sometimes it's the right answer, but sometimes you need to go next door, and sometimes you need to go from Montreal to Moscow.  In many cases where an array is close to the right answer but you want a standard-library, std::valarray is what you want.  And in many cases an array is, in fact, the right answer.

Comment: @Brooks. I can think of any situation where a dynamically allocated array can not be replaced efficiently with a std::vector. This is because a std::vector __IS__ an array (the only difference is that the vector handles all the memory management). If it is a statically allocated array fine you may get a tiny performance improvement with just using an array.

Comment: Technically, `std::vector` is **not** an array, but a class (why do you say that it is an array, but then say "the only difference is"?). But non-technically (speaking loyally) it is an array because the usage is similarly.

Comment: @райтфолд While yes, the `new[]` example I gave would leak if exceptions are thrown, I *never* endorsed initializing that way: I said, "If you initialized the array as...".  I will amend my `std::vector` recommendation to emphasize the exception safety aspect, though.

Comment: @BrooksMoses: +1 for mentioning `std::valarray`. std::vecotr is not just a pointer plus new/delete: it also track size, capacity and what required to grow and shrink. What an array, once allocated, don't  and valarray also doesn't, making it structurally simpler.

Comment: Funny... I get a crash by calling `delete[]`.  And I'm creating an array of objects exactly like that.  I think whether it works depends on the class.

Comment: @PauloCarvalho No, it doesn't depend on the class.  It depends on whether the array was created with `new[]`.  If `delete[]` crashes when destroying a `new[]`-allocated array, you're doing something else wrong (such as corrupting your heap).

Answer (score 19):

Just `delete[] array`  is sufficient. It is guaranteed that each element of the array is deleted when you delete an array using `delete[]` operator.

Answer (score 14):

As a general rule you should `delete`/`delete[]` exactly those things that you allocated with `new`/`new[]`. In this case you have one allocation with `new[]`, so you should use one call to `delete[]` to free that allocated thing again.

That the `delete`s in the for-loop won't compile is also a good indication that they are not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 9):

Not only is

```
delete [] array;
```

enough, but if you do

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    delete &array[i];
delete[] array;
```

you'll be causing undefined behavior, because

```
delete &array[i];
```

will be deleting things that weren't returned by a `new` operation.

Not to mention that the subsequent `delete[] array;` will call the destructor for all the objects that just had destructors called in the loop.

So don't do that.

Answer (score 8):

```
delete [] array
```

is enough.