# Using char* in std::strcpy

Tags: c++

Here's my code...

```
char* m1;
char* m2 = "sth";
strcpy(m1, m2);
```

That code threw run-time errors, so I tried...

```
char m1[];
char m2[] = "sth";
```

That can run with no errors. However, I want to use...

`char* s`

What sould I do?

Comment: `strcpy` requires enough space at the destination. Any reason you can't use `std::string`?

Comment: I would recommed.. char *m1 = malloc( sizof(char) * (strlen(m2) + 1));
and declare m2 first. then you dont need to worry about magic numbers.

Comment: @MarsRover: `sizeof(char)` is redundant as it is always 1 by definition.

Comment: I like putting in the sizeof(char) as it gets optimized out and improves code readability

Comment: @Minion91: you could make a case for putting `sizeof(*m1)`, but `sizeof(char)` is just needless clutter.

Comment: @PaulR I disagree, sizeof(char) indicates the type of the malloced resource

Comment: @Minion91: adding redundant information that the compiler ignores but that educates readers is what comments are for :-) Anyway, this is C++, MarsRover's code doesn't compile because `malloc` returns `void*`, which doesn't convert to `char*` implicitly in C++. Once fixed, the cast would indicate the type for a *third* time on one line, how much indication do you think the reader needs before they believe you that you wanted some `char`s?

Comment: @Minion91: it is better to use `sizeof(*m1)` so that if the type should change in the future (e.g. say it changes to `wchar_t`) you only need to make the change in one place - had you used `sizeof(char)` then you would need to change it in two places, and then guess what might happen ? ;-) This is known as the SPOT (Single Point Of Truth) principle.

Comment: @PaulR: well, in C++03 you still have to change it in two places (the definition of the pointer `m1` and the cast of the result of `malloc`). In C++11 you could do that cast by `static_cast<decltype(m1)>` in order that one place specifies the type, and everything else follows. Or you could use something a bit more C++-friendly than `malloc`.

Comment: @Steve: yes, but at least the compiler will catch the mistake if you forget to change the type of the cast, whereas forgetting to change `sizeof(char)` in the call to malloc will compile without warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are not allocating any memory to store the result of the strcpy method. You need:

```
char* m1 = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 4) /* 4 being the size of 3 chars + trailing \0 */
char* m2 = "sth";
```

Than you can do the strcpy

And in the end you have to free any dynamically allocated memory a.g.

```
free(m1)
```

m2 is allocated statically and doesn't has to be freed.

Comment: Question is tagged as C++, not C.

Comment: Then, I have to FREE my m1. haven't I?

Comment: yes. but you should check if you want C or C++, as your code is mostly C, but is tagged C++. you can look into the c++ string method, unique/shared pointers.

Comment: Thanks guy, I forgot to cast (char *) and replied something stupid as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should `allocate` memory for `m1`.
For example

```
char* m1 = new char[4];
char* m2 = "sth";
strcpy(m1, m2);
// so smth with m1
delete[] m1;
```

But since you write on C++, why you not use `std::string`?

Comment: The last sentence (of an answer!) shouldn't be a question although the intent of the (rethorical) question is clear.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you would rather do:

```
// don't forget to #include <string>
std::string m1;
std::string m2 = "sth";
m1 = m2;
```

if you then need a `const char*` (e.g., for some API call) you can get one

```
const char* str = m1.c_str();
```

Problem gone.

Plus, you don't need to bother with buffer sizes and proper deallocation anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I believe even your 2nd example is also invalid

```
char m1[];
char m2[] = "sth";
```

m1 is not having any valid piece of memory to store the copied data.  And, I believe you should have the array dimension in your declaration (you are not declaring a method param here)

Normally you should have something like

```
char m1[10];
char m2[] = "sth"; 
strcpy(m1, m2);
```

Go back to the question.  Many people said you should allocate memory in order to use char*.  It is not wrong, but more accurately, you should have the pointer pointing to valid piece of memory.

Allocating memory is one way, but you can also do something like this:

```
char outdata[100];
char* m1 = &(outdata[10]);
char* m2 = "foo";
strcpy(m1, m2);
```

no explicit allocation here, and still a valid example.

I believe OP is still not understanding what is an array and what is a pointer.  Get some extra reading and thinking on that.

Comment: I'd like to know why I am given a downvote as I believe what I said is all valid

Comment: Not only valid but useful, too, I think. +1

Answer (score -2):

First of all, before you perform the copy you must assure that the destination pointer have enough memory to keep the copy, if you don't you'll get runtime errors. So you need this:

```
char* m1;
char* m2 = "sth";
m1 = new char[strlen(m2)+1]; // <---- reserve memory for m1
strcpy(m1, m2);
// remember to delete[] m1
```

Another way to deal with character strings is to use the `std::string` class instead, if you do, the memory management will not bother you.

```
std::string m1("");
std::string m2("sth");
m1 = m2; // no strcopy needed, no memory management needed
```

Finally, if for some reason you must deal with pointers, take care of the new/delete pair and remenber that the [memory reserved with new[] must be deleted wit delete[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486034/delete-an-array-of-objects).

And and additional advice: instead of `memcpy` i preffer the use of `std::copy`:

```
char* m1;
char* m2 = "sth";
m1 = new char[strlen(m2)+1]; // <---- reserve memory for m1
std::copy(std::begin(m2), std::end(m2), std::begin(m1));
// remember to delete[] m1
```

Because it works both for the `char *` and the `std::string` version if you use `std::begin` and `std::end` functions:

```
std::string m1("");
std::string m2("sth");
std::copy(std::begin(m2), std::end(m2), std::begin(m1));
```

Edit: It works as long the `m2` are statically reserved so the length can be deduced at compile time.

Comment: `m1 = new char[strlen(m2)]; // <---- reserve memory for m1` you forgot +1. strlen returns length of string without null terminator.

Comment: `std::begin` and `std::end` work with arrays but they don't work with pointers.

Comment: [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) works both with arrays and pointers ;)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Erm, no, they don't. You may want to read the documentation you linked to.

Comment: Yes, you're right @R.MartinhoFernandes, it works with *static arrays* not with *dynamic arrays*, but **both of them are pointers**, I misunderstood you.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster *None of them are pointers*. You may want to read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4810668/46642

Comment: Good point @R.MartinhoFernandes I found the answer you posted very useful! Thanks to you I realized that I was confused about the pointer decayment.