# How to deallocate a structure of dynamic size

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [delete[] an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486034/delete-an-array-of-objects)

The memory is allocated as follows:

```
struct foo {
  int size;
  int * arr;
};

(*structA).arr = new int[(*structA).size];
```

How does one deallocate it?

Comment: You just call "delete (*structA).arr;" and you are golden? No need to specify how much memory needs to be freed.

Comment: General rule: exactly one `delete` for each `new`, exactly one `delete[]` for each `new[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory allocated will be deleted when you call

```
delete[] (*structA).arr;
```

As for your struct, it depends on whether you allocated your struct on the heap or the stack.

Comment: Just one additional question: how would I do that with 2-dimensional array of structures? Defined like this: int (*foo)[2] = new int[size][2];

Comment: Exactly the same. "delete[] foo;" and you are good. You can test this with a debugger, and check the application's current memory usage.

Answer (score 4):

Anything you allocate with `new[]` must be deleted with `delete[]`:

```
structA->arr = new int[structA->size];
...
delete[] structA->arr;
```

In this particular example, it would be better to use `std::vector` instead.  Let it handle the memory allocation and deallocation for you.  You can use its `size()` method to determine how many items it is holding:

```
struct foo {
  std::vector<int> arr;
};

structA->arr.resize(some value here);
...
int size = structA->arr.size();
```

Comment: This looks nice, thanks - but originally, I programmed the whole thing using vectors and it was too slow to pass some authomated benchmarks so I rewrote it using arrays.

Comment: @Grant : I guarantee `vector<>` was not the source of your bottlenecks.

Comment: Vectors are just as fast as new[arraySize], so they will not be the slowdown. (well, minisculely slower, but completely and utterly neglible)

Comment: `vector` allocation of POD types is just as fast as a raw array. I'm guessing that the `vector` was probably being passed around by value, so a lot of time was wasted making copy-constructed temps.