# Memory allocated with new int[10] must be deallocated with delete[]

Tags: c++, memory

Statement:

> Memory allocated with new int[10] must be deallocated with delete[].

So..

```
new int[10];
```

Then how do I delete it?

EDIT:
Thank you guys :)
I think Wilson, Paul, Tim etc. are right, the statement omit some words therefore confused me - -...it's simply

```
int * p = new int[10];

delete [] p;
```

I've never seen Rob's answer though, looks really new to me! Any explanation will be appreciated.:)

```
delete[] new int[10];
```

Comment: You can't delete it because you have no handle to it.

Comment: To maintain the same style, `delete[] new int[10];`

Comment: You should use `std::vector<int>`. I don't remember when I wrote `delete` or `delete []` last time in code.

Comment: Perhaps not an exact duplicate, but worth a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486034/delete-an-array-of-objects

Comment: @Robᵩ That looks interesting to me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a variable to hold the value returned from new.  You should have something like:

```
int* intArray = new int[10];
```

then later when you want to delete the memory, you reference it through the variable:

```
delete[] intArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like it says:

```
int *foo = new int[10];
delete[] foo;
```

Comment: if I will not delete any memory and program exits. Then there could be any risk? ( Mean we just need to delete memory on run time? )

Answer (score 1):

```
int * p = new int[10]; // allocate p

// do stuff with p

delete [] p;           // release p when you're done
```

Comment: if I will not delete any memory and program exits. Then there could be any risk? Someone told me that if we will not deallocate the memory and program exit, then that memory will unusable until operator system reinstalled.

Comment: Most modern operating systems will clean up remaining memory allocations on program exit, but it's a good idea to free all dynamic allocations anyway - it makes it easier to find memory leaks and it may become important if the program is re-architected.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "clear/clean the memory" ?