# C++, delete[] foo and delete foo

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

I just can't get used to C++ syntax yet..
any intuitive explanation on

```
//delete [] foo
// and 
//delete foo[]
```

would be very appreciated.
to be more precise, let's say I have

```
int** foo = new int*[50]
for (int index = 0; index<50;++index)
     foo[index] = new int[50]

//foo = 2d 50x50 matrix
//now lets say i want to deallocate the memory of this matrix

for (index index=0;index<50;++index)
     delete[] foo[index]
delete[] foo
```

now I know I need to delete all the "inner" pointers that I've allocated before and then delete the pointer to a pointer.
but, my question is, what IS the `[]` after the delete used for? i mean if you leave it empty all the time why is even there? does it get any parameter some times? or we always just `delete[] foo`?

Comment: if you use `new X[]` then you must use `delete[]`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2486055

Comment: There are two different *delete* operators. One for deleting single objects (`delete`) and one for deleting arrays of objects (`delete[]`). The `[]` simply differentiated between the different *delete* operators.