# C++ when to use delete[] and properly deallocate memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++98

So I see that there's pairings with memory management functions such as `malloc/free`, `new/delete`, and `new[]/delete[]`, but sometimes you're not always calling `new` or `new[]` and you still have to call `delete`, `delete[]`, or `free`. For example, [strdup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y471khhc.aspx) is one such function which encapsulates the allocation of memory and you'd still have to deallocate that memory yourself later on.

So when do you know to free memory, if you're not always writing `new` or `malloc` in some sense? I'm particularly curious about [deleting arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486034/delete-an-array-of-objects). Just simple arrays. Because, that seems to be one of the use cases that `delete[]` is made for. (I'm looking at [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/).)

So, is this valid? Is this necessary? Is anything missing?

```
unsigned char bytes[4] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF};
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    std::cout << std::hex << +bytes[i];
delete[] bytes;
```

`bytes` is technically an `unsigned char *` type, right? I know I technically have a pointer, but because this isn't an array of objects, I'm unsure whether or not it gets automatically destroyed.

Comment: You only need to `delete`/`delete[]` stuff that you have previously created with `new`/`new[]`

Comment: This is not necessarily true -- `strdup` can cause memory leaks if you don't delete.

Comment: `strdup` is non-standard, and you should `free()` the pointer it returns, not `delete` it, since it uses `malloc` internally.

Comment: *"So when do you know to free memory, if you're not always writing new or malloc in some sense? "* -- By looking at the documentation of the function. Note that the documentation of `_strdup` that you linked to says that it calls `malloc`, and it also explicitly tells you that the memory must be freed with `free()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> C++ when to use delete[] and properly deallocate memory?

When the memory was allocated memory with `new[]` and that memory has not yet been deallocated, and won't be deallocated by anyone else.

> So, is this valid?

Not valid. What you've shown has undefined behaviour. You may not deallocate automatic variables. You may not call `delete[]` on anything that wasn't allocated with `new[]`.

> Is this necessary?

Not necessary. *Automatic* variables are destroyed... automatically, when they go out of scope.

> `bytes` is technically an `unsigned char *` type, right?
>
> I know I technically have a pointer

Not right. `bytes` is in all regards, an array. Not a pointer.

> So is C++ different from C in that regard about pointers to arrays?

Not different. Arrays are arrays in C as well.

You may be confused with array decaying. When used in a value context, array name will decay into a pointer to first element. The pointer that the array decays into is a pointer, but the array is not. Example:

```
int  arr[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4}; // an array
int* ptr  = arr;            // a pointer; arr decays and is assignable to a pointer
int* ptr2 = &arr[0]         // decaying is syntactic sugar for this
int size1 = sizeof arr;     // size of the array == sizeof(int)*4
int size2 = sizeof ptr;     // size of the pointer == sizeof(int*)
```

Also, in a function argument list, array declaration is the same as a pointer declaration. Which is highly confusing. You just have to remember that arrays can not be passed by value, so an array as function argument must mean something else.

```
void foo(int[4]); // confusing
void foo(int*);   // actually means this
```

Comment: So is C++ different from C in that regard about pointers to arrays?

Comment: @Peri461 see the illustrative examples that I added to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not valid.

Every single call to `delete[]` should be paired with `new[]`.  If it doesn't pair up (e.g. `strdup`), it's because some function internally calls `malloc`/`new[]`.

`unsigned char bytes[4] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF};` declares 4 bytes of memory on the *stack*.  Stack memory is automatically destroyed at the end of the enclosing [scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope).  They share the same memory as those needed for function calls.

`new`/`delete` allocates and deallocates *heap* memory.  Heap memory has no specific order of acquisition or destruction (unlike a *stack*, which is [first-in-last-out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type))), so you have to `delete` it explicitly or the program won't know when to deallocate it.